# Angular folders/files structure for a simple app (style guide)

Tags: angular, coding-style, angular2-styleguide

I’m studying angular’s style guide and I got some doubts while developing a simple app! The app is to control user’s stock exchange shares. So it’s needed:

- a module to authenticate user (signin, signup and reset password)
- a module with a component to show all user’s stocks and another one to add new stocks
- a module to edit user’s profile

Authentication module will have a different layout from the rest of app (authentication will have just a centralised form while rest of app will have a nav-bar as menu).

**Question 1:** I’ll create a component called Layout inside Auth module and use it only for authentication views; Where do I create the Layout component or module (I don’t know which one) to use with the rest of app? Should I create a Core module and inside this module a Layout module? Should I create a core module and a layout module (outside of core)?

**Question 2:** where should I create the guard for authentication? This guard will be used for Stocks and Profile modules to avoid users that aren’t logged in

**Question 3:** how would you structure this simple project regarding folders and files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I'm using this [article](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a) to organize my Angular folder structure. Basically, we have three main folders - **core**, **shared**, **views**.

- **core**: it has the `CoreModule` which provides all app common services. It's imported only once in `AppModule`. In this folder, I have services and guards subfolders because they are injectables (**question 2 answer**). guards I don't provide at `CoreModule`, I provide them at [routing](https://angular.io/guide/module-types) modules, i.e `AppRoutingModule`.
- **shared**: it has the `SharedModule` which declare and exports all app common components, pipes, enums, classes and directives (all classes expect services and guards). `SharedModule` is imported by `views` module.
- **views**: it gets all views modules (generally lazy-load modules).

The structure is (**question 3 answer**):

```
/app
|---/core
|   |---/guards
|   |---/services
|   |---core.module.ts
|
|---/shared
|   |---/components
|   |---/directives
|   ...
|   |---shared.module.ts
|
|---/views
|   |---/view-X
|       |---/components
|       |---/directives
|       |---view-X.component.html
|       |---view-X.component.css
|       |---view-X.component.spec.ts
|       |---view-X.component.ts
|       |---view-X.module.ts
|       |---view-X-routing.module.ts
```

In your case, could have three views folders/modules: authenticate, user-stock and user-edit. Each one will have the structure similar to the `view-X` folder example (**question 1 answer**).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering!!
I liked your way of organizing the project, but I got two questions:
 
**1-** would I create the Layouts (for authentication and app) inside shared folder?!

**2-** in app/core/services are the services that communicate with API?

Comment: **1-** It depends. If the layout is used only for authentication, I'd create in /views/authentication. If it is used for other modules (user-edit and user-stock), I'd create at /app/shared because them can import `SharedModule` and have access to the common layout. **2-** `CoreModule` has all common services, like API service. `CoreModule` is provided ONLY in `AppModule` to inject the services only once.

Comment: Got it!! Not sure how the project would look like when it gets bigger, but for now, I think it's clean and easy enough to implement new features!! Thanks Pedro!!

Comment: @MuriloBoaretoDelefrate, you're welcome. Folder and project structure is a subject I have a lot of interest and I'd like to ask you if you discover another way to structure an Angular project, share with us :)

Comment: Sure!! As soon as I finish the project, I'll update my question with the structure I ended up with!